# Get audio samples from byte array

Tags: c++, qt, audio

How to get data samples from QAudioInput

I found in this examples code from audioinput example code

```
    void InputTest::readMore()
{
    if(!m_audioInput)
        return;
    qint64 len = m_audioInput->bytesReady();
    if(len > 4096)
        len = 4096;
    qint64 l = m_input->read(m_buffer.data(), len);
    if(l > 0) {
        m_audioInfo->write(m_buffer.constData(), l);
    }
}
```

I understood that m_buffer contains audio data samples

but my audio processing library receives short samples 
How I can convert this to short pointer

My audio library function like this

```
putSample( short *Sample, int numberOfSample)
```

I can get number of samples from

```
Q_ASSERT(m_format.sampleSize() % 8 == 0);
        const int channelBytes = m_format.sampleSize() / 8;
        const int sampleBytes = m_format.channels() * channelBytes;
        Q_ASSERT(len % sampleBytes == 0);
        const int numSamples = len / sampleBytes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html) indicates read() is expecting a char* to store the data in. If you have set up the format of the audio device properly the data will indeed be 'segmented' as shorts in the char array and you can simply cast the char* to a short* before passing it to your library.